# Tkinter: Can't get StringVar() value from separate function

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I've been stuck for far longer than I'd like on trying to get the value of a StringVar that was entered into a Tkinter entry widget from a separate login function.

I first declared them as a global variable (I know this is bad practice but I'm not sure how else to access the variable from another function), then called the .get() method inside the Login function and printed it to see if it worked, to which nothing appears. I printed the variable by itself to see if if was being passed and I get PY_VAR0, but when I print it with a .get() method, nothing prints. Here is my code:

```
class LoginScreen(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set the title of the window
        self.title("Horizon Cinemas - Log In")

        # Creating the login form's frame
        self.root = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.root.grid(padx=20, pady=10)

        # Greeting widget
        greet_label = Label(self.root, text="Please enter your credentials", font="Arial")
        greet_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady = 2)

        # Login widget
        global username_verify
        global password_verify

        username_verify = tk.StringVar()
        password_verify = tk.StringVar()

        self.u_label = Label(self.root, text="Staff ID:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
        self.u_entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=username_verify)
        self.u_entry.grid(row = 1, column=1, pady=2)

        self.p_label = Label(self.root, text="Password:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
        self.p_entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=password_verify)
        self.p_entry.grid(row = 2, column=1, pady=2)

        self.login_button = ttk.Button(master=self, text="Login")
        self.login_button['command'] = self.login_func()
        self.login_button.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=20)


    def login_func(self): # SQLite connection func
        connection = sqlite3.connect("horizon_cinemas.db")  
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        print(username_verify.get())
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I've looked at examples on other sites and they apparently worked, but when I apply that to my code, nothing happens.

**EDIT**: After testing the answer posted by @toyota Supra in a separate file, it appears to work, though when used in my main code, it then stops working.

At the bottom of my file, I have this to run the GUI on start:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = Main()
  app.mainloop()
```

After changing `app = Main()` to `app = LoginScreen()`, it works. I assume I need to put a mainloop() somewhere in my code but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Is the code run from `Main` class? If yes, the problem may be caused by multiple instances of `Tk`.  Use `Toplevel` for `LoginScreen`.  Also fix the indentation of your posted code. Another issue is `self.login_button['command'] = self.login_func()` should be `self.login_button['command'] = self.login_func`.

Comment: @acw1668 The code in the question is in a separate class from `Main`, to put it simply `Main` is a GUI that includes a button that opens a separate login window that uses the `LoginScreen` class. I will give your solution a try and let you know.

Comment: @acw1668 Changing `class LoginScreen(tk.Tk):` to class `LoginScreen(tk.Toplevel):` worked! Thank you so much, I was losing hair trying to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


class LoginScreen(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set the title of the window
        self.title("Horizon Cinemas - Log In")

        # Creating the login form's frame
        self.root = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.root.grid(padx=20, pady=10)

        # Greeting widget
        greet_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Please enter your credentials", font="Arial")
        greet_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady = 2)

        # Login widget
        global username_verify
        global password_verify

        username_verify = tk.StringVar()
        password_verify = tk.StringVar()

        self.u_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Staff ID:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
        self.u_entry = ttk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=username_verify)
        self.u_entry.grid(row = 1, column=1, pady=2)

        self.p_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Password:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
        self.p_entry = ttk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=password_verify)
        self.p_entry.grid(row = 2, column=1, pady=2)

        self.login_button = ttk.Button(master=self, text="Login")
        self.login_button['command'] = self.login_func 
        self.login_button.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=20)


    def login_func(self): # SQLite connection func
        #connection = sqlite3.connect("horizon_cinemas.db")  
        #cursor = connection.cursor()

        print(username_verify.get())

window = LoginScreen()    
window.mainloop()
```

Which gives a result like this (notice the `.get` result is printed to the terminal):

[image]

Comment: Weirdly when I put the code into a separate test file and run it, it works, but doesn't when I use it in my main code. I have a suspicion I'm missing a mainloop().

Comment: Btw, I don't used qlite3.

Comment: It works when I put it into a separate file and test it, but when I use it in my main code it doesn't work.

Comment: It is like this if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = LoginScreen()
  app.mainloop()

Comment: But I don't see Main() class instead of LoginScreen(). It is up to you.